# Python - Number with a variable part

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a number given in this form 623746xyz3 and i have to code a Python script that prints on screen all numbers that can be created with the combination of all values (from 0 to 9 ) that x,y,z can assume. 
Can someone help me?

Comment: Use three nested loops and [`string.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those `xyz` are always next to each other, you can just loop from 0 to 999 and `replace` that part of the string accordingly.

```
s = "623746xyz3"
for xyz in range(1000):
    sxyz = s.replace('xyz', str(xyz))
    print int(sxyz)
```

In case the `x`, `y`, and `z` can be more 'spread out', you will need three nested loops:

```
for x in range(10):
    sx = s.replace('x', str(x))
    for y in range(10):
        sxy = sx.replace('y', str(y))
        for z in range(10):
            sxyz = sxy.replace('z', str(z))
            print int(sxyz)
```

(And in case you do not know the 'variables' a priori, you will first need to find the non-digit characters and use a recursive approach to replace them.)

Answer (score 1):

My first idea:

```
for x in range(0, 10)
    for y in range(0. 10)
        for z in range (0, 10)
            print 6*1000000000+2*100000000+3*10000000+7*1000000+4*100000+6*10000+x*1000+y*100+z*10+3
```